# Use of an anonymous function callback to split array based on value

Tags: php, arrays, callback, split

Given an array `$arr` of the form:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ([id] => id1, ...)
    [1] => Array ([id] => id1, ...)
    [2] => Array ([id] => id2, ...)
    ...
)
```

Using this foreach loop:

```
$rowsById = [];
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    $rowsById[$row['id']][] = $row;
}
```

We can transform it to an array of the form (keyed by ids):

```
Array (
    [id1] => Array (
                 [0] => Array ([id] => id1, ...)
                 [1] => Array ([id] => id1, ...)
             )
    [id2] => Array (
                 [0] => Array ([id] => id2, ...)
             )
    ...
)
```

***Can we do the same thing but without the foreach loop?***
(That is, with some iterating function like array_walk and a callback)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$map = array();
array_walk($arr, function($row, $i) use(&$map) { $map[$row['id']][] = $row; });
```

From a formal point of view, this solution is a positive answer to your question.

**But**, if you wanted to speed up the code, or even if you wanted cleaner code without loosing too much somewhere else, here is the surprise: this solution is definitely **slower** than your `foreach` loop (by a factor of **3** on my machine). The reason is almost certainly the function call to the anonymous function, which is absent in the foreach solution. As I already pointed out in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721618/php-object-arrays-not-linearly-scale-while-global-arrays-do/10806300#10806300) here on SO, *it's the function calls that eat up CPU time*.

This situation could be different if we could just combine simple `array_` functions to obtain the same result, but the fact that `['id']` must be accessed somehow, the overhead of creating intermediate arrays, plus the fact that no `array_` function is available for direct assignment to keyed bins, make this an impossible task.

For example, this code that I posted before realizing that it was *wrong* (because it replaces instead of appending to the bins)

```
$map = array_combine(array_map(function($a) { return $a['id']; }, $arr), $arr);
```

runs slower than your `foreach` by a factor of **2.5** on my machine.

So, at the end, the answer to your question is: "Yes, if we don't care about processing time".

Comment: This won't work, the resulting array will have a single value for each key rather than an array of values.

Comment: I assume that the thrust of this Q is to hoist Opcode execution into the more efficient C(++) encoded library calls.  The problem with this solution is that you are still executing the same number of PHP opcodes per array element, so I doubt that there will be a material change in runtime.

Comment: @TerryE unfortunately you are right. Furthermore I'm about to correct that `array_reduce` into an `array_walk`, in order to avoid the array copy when adding an element

Comment: @JRL: OK, now my answer is stable. If someone is able to come up with something really better I'll +1, promised

Comment: @JRL: my answer was not stable enough, apparently. Except for the first 2 lines, I have completely rewritten it again...